# C++ add objects to vector

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm not sure if my approach is correct, so I'm asking you to verify please.
I'm trying to add individual objects to an 2D Vector. This is the code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<*Tree>> treeVector(100);

for (auto &j : treeVector)
        j.assign(treeVector.size(), new Tree(0, 0));
```

The class is called `Tree`. The Code works but it seems like there are objects doubled in the vector?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like you need a `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tree>>> treeVector(100);` actually.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be storing pointers?

Comment: not sure .. I also tried without pointers. Doesn't make a big difference. But nevertheless. Same problem occurs without using pointers ..

Comment: If you don't have to have a pointer (I try to avoid them most of the time) then you can use `std::vector<std::vector<Tree>> treeVector(100, std::vector<Tree>(100));` and your done.

Comment: @NathanOliver and than fill the vector like this?
`for (int i = 0; i < treeVector.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < treeVector.size(); j++) {
            treeVector[i][j] = *new tree(0, 0);
        }
    }`

Comment: @Leo.1906 No.  The vector would already be full of default constructed `Tree`s.

Answer (score 2):

The loop

```
for (auto &j : treeVector)
  j.assign(treeVector.size(), new Tree(0, 0));
```

is equivalent to

```
for (auto &j : treeVector) {
  Tree *tmp = new Tree(0, 0);
  j.assign(treeVector.size(), tmp);
}
```

Only one Tree is allocated and constructed in each iteration, and each element(`std::vector<Tree *>`) of treeVector will contains 100 pointers which point to a same object.

What you want might be:

```
for (auto &j : treeVector) {
  for (int i=0; i<treeVector.szie(); ++i)
    j.push_back(new Tree(0,0));
}
```

And you might want to use `std::unique_ptr` instead, which will help with managing the memory.

Comment: and what would be correct?